# Adaptive Gaussian filtering with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, filtering, ndimage

Running a Gaussian filter over image with static sigma value is easy:

```
scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(input, sigma)
```

But how to do this with a `sigma` value that is different for each pixel? For example, I might have another NumPy array of the same size that indicates what sigma to use for each pixel.

Comment: The request is to blur every pixel differently. There is another "image" which says, how much should be each pixel blured.

Will give DIPlib a try - thank you @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an adaptive Gaussian filter implementation in OpenCV, scipy.ndimage or scikit-image. [DIPlib](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) does have such a filter (disclosure: I'm an author). You can install it with `pip install diplib`.

This is how you would use the adaptive Gaussian filter where only the size of the kernel changes (this function also can rotate an elongated Gaussian, it's pretty neat, I recommend you play around with that!).

```py
import diplib as dip

img = dip.ImageRead('examples/trui.ics')

# We need an image that indicates the kernel orientation for each pixel,
# we just set this to 0
orientation = img.Similar('SFLOAT')
orientation.Fill(0)
# We need an image that indicates the kernel size for each pixel,
# this is your NumPy array
scale = dip.CreateRadiusCoordinate(img.Sizes()) / 200
# This is the function. Kernel sizes in the `scale` image are multiplied
# by the sigmas given here
out = dip.AdaptiveGauss(img, [orientation, scale], sigmas=[5,5])

dip.ImageWrite(img,'so_in.jpg')
dip.ImageWrite(out,'so_out.jpg')
```

Do note that image objects in the Python bindings to DIPlib are compatible with NumPy arrays.